# How can I print from a webView in android?

Tags: printing, webview, android-webview

I have a webView app that displays a website.
In that website there is a print button which webView does not permit to use the window.print() method.
How can I capture the event triggered by that button to than make it trigger printing natively on android studio?
Is using JsBridge the way to go?

tried adding a native button to print, but it is not the solution I'm looking for.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.